# Q: How to change the parallelism value only in the case of master branch?(CircleCI2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I use CircleCI2.0 in my rails app.

I want to change the parallelism value only when master branch.

so I set the circleci/config.yml like below.

but it doesn't work. just Error occured.

It's possible to adjust Parallelism for the particular branch?

please give me any hint or advise.

thanks.

```
 version: 2
 jobs:
   build:
    if [ $CIRCLE_BRANCH = "master" ]; then
      parallelism: 2
    else
      parallelism: 8
    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

No, not really. The way you're trying to do it cannot be done and the simplest answer is that you can't do it.

What you can do as a workaround, and use [CircleCI Workflows](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/) and duplicate the job. Then, with filters, have one version of it run only with `master` and `2x` parallelism and the other run for all branches other than `master` with `8x` parallelism.

This is going to cause some redundant lines in the YAML though. Much of which you can deduplicate using [YAML anchors](https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-hacks-reuse-yaml-in-your-circleci-config-with-yaml/).